# Return exception populated in a function

Tags: python, exception

My code is like this:

```
try:
    function()
except:
    #Error
```

Function code:

```
def function():
    try:
        #something
    except:
        #function error
```

Is it possible to somehow return the error returned from the function if there is some? And if there is non just return #error instead.

Something like this

```
    try:
        function()
    except:
        if #function error:
            #function error
        #error
```

Comment: What's the use case for this pattern? It's an abnormal design to want to return an `Exception`, rather than `raise` one.

Comment: @dsoencer currently I am doing some webscraping using selenium. I am in development phase and wanted to make sure that everything is working as expected. in the main try block I am calling function that gets the data however, sometimes the function called fails without any errors returned from the function so I wanted to check how many errors are returned from function directly and how many are returned due to some other reason. (to help me understand why exactly it is failing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with the following syntax:

```
def function():
    try:
        #something
    except Exception as e:
        return e
```

In your outer code where you call the function, you don't need to have a `try, except` because the function is *returning* an `Exception` not *raising* it. You can instead check if the return value of the function is an instance of `Exception`, like this:

```
result = function()
if isinstance(result, Exception):
    #handle error
else:
    #do whatever you want with result
```

Alternatively, you can just let the function raise the error if it occurs, and then handle it in your calling code, rather than returning the error, like this:

```
def function():
    #do whatever error-prone code

try:
    result = function()
    #do whatever you want with result
except Exception as e:
    #handle error
```

Comment: and how would the main except look like? `except: if e: print(e) else: #error`?

Comment: @Roitko no problem, let me know if you still have trouble

Comment: @Roitko also the last part of my answer is usually a better pattern for handling errors in your functions, unless you have a specific reason for wanting to return the error, as an error occuring in the function can be handled from where you call the function